# Side effects of changing the "RegisteredOwner" key

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

I changed my username long ago for my Windows 7 computer, but one outstanding issue is some applications still know me by my old username. A quick registry search found the name under

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOwner

I found my old username under several other program-specific registry keys as well. If I change my "RegisteredOwner" key to my current username, will this have negative consequences on other applications that already have their own copy of "RegisteredOwner"?

Answer (score 1):

The "Registered owner" is unrelated to any account's real name or username, except by coincidence (which would be reasonable to happen on a home computer with one human user)!

Its only apparent purpose is to customize Windows's own About boxes (as seen with `winver.exe`), the System control panel applet (WinKey+Pause), and to provide a default for other programs which have an independent setting for an equivalent string...